# Third Moment of Standard Normal Random Variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a normal random variable with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma^2$. I am wondering how to calculate the third moment of a normal random variable without having a huge mess to integrate. Is there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: $E(X-\mu)^3=0$. Expand the LHS.

Comment: Standard normal or not?

Comment: Just normal--thanks for the vocabulary correction.

Comment: A normal distribution is symmetric about the mean.  The skewness is thus zero.

Answer (score 9):

$\mathbb{E}[(X-\mu)^3]=0$ since $X-\mu$ is normally distributed with mean zero, then expand out the cube.

Comment: By the way, standard normal often refers to $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$.

Comment: That makes sense. Do I have to integrate still if it was standard normal, not just normal?

Comment: If $X$ is normally distributed with mean zero, then $\mathbb{E}[X^n]=0$ for all odd integers $n$.

Comment: After expanding it, how do we compute $\mathbb{E}(X^3)$? We would get many other terms?

Comment: Sure, but all the other terms can be determined fairly easily since we know the mean and variance of $X$.

Comment: @carmichael561 Sorry, I am still kinda confused. Like I don't know how to compute $\mathbb{E}(3x\mu^2)$

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[3\mu^2 X]=3\mu^2\mathbb{E}[X]=3\mu^3$. Similarly, $\mathbb{E}[3\mu X^2]=3\mu\mathbb{E}[X^2]=3\mu(\sigma^2+\mu^2)$ since $\mathrm{var}(X)=\sigma^2$.

Answer (score 7):

This is a general method to calculate any moment:

Let $X$ be standard normal. The moment generating function is:

$$M_X(t) = E(e^{tX}) = e^{t^2/2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(x-t)^2/2} \:\:dx = e^{t^2/2}$$

since the integrand is the pdf of $N(t,1)$.

Specifically for the third moment you differentiate $M_X(t)$
three times

$M_X^{(3)}(t) = (t^3 + 3t)e^{t^2/2}$

and

$E[X^3] = M_X^{(3)}(0) = 0$

---

For a general normal variable $Y = \sigma X + \mu$ we have that

$$M_Y(t) = e^{\mu t} M_X(\sigma t) = e^{\mu t + \sigma^2 t^2 /2} $$

and you calculate the $n$th moment as a above, i.e. differentiating $n$ times and setting $t=0$: $$E[Y^n] = M_Y^{(n)}(0).$$

Answer (score 3):

If the distribution of a random variable $X$ is symmetric about $0$, meaning $\Pr(X>x)=\Pr(X<-x)$ for every $x>0$, then its third moment, if it exists at all, must be $0$, as must all of its odd-numbered moments.

If $\operatorname{E}\left[ \,|X^3|\, \right]<\infty$ then the third moment exists.  Furthermore, Symmetry shows that the positive and negative parts of $\operatorname{E}\left[ X^3 \right]<0$ (without the absolute-value sign) cancel each other out.

Comment: +1 for mentioning third moments would cancel negative and positive parts. I also want to ask if the perfect normal distribution will have +ve 4th moment?

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER : The normal distribution, of any mean and variance, has moments of all orders.

Comment: This is what confuses me. Normal distribution has mean and variance (1st and 2nd) moments as being described as sufficient statistic. Then why does it even have moments of all orders when the first and second is sufficient. I posted this [question here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/461836/sufficient-statistic-for-normal-distribution-mean-variance-kurtosis?noredirect=1#comment854769_461836) but not too satisfied with the comments

Comment: I guess the original question was broader since it asked for the third moment given that the normal distribution isn't necessarily centered around 0.

Answer (score 3):

Given the questions expressed under carmichael561's answer, let us look at the details:
\begin{align}
0 = {} & \operatorname E\big( (X-\mu)^3\big) \\[8pt]
= {} & \operatorname E\big( X^3 - 3X^2 \mu +3X\mu^2 - \mu^3\big) \\[8pt]
= {} & \operatorname E(X^3) - 3\mu\operatorname E(X^2) + 3\mu^2\operatorname E(X) - \mu^3 \\[8pt]
= {} & \operatorname E(X^3) - 3\mu\big( \mu^2+\sigma^2) + 3\mu^2\big(\mu\big) - \mu^3 \\[8pt]
= {} & \operatorname E(X^3) -3\mu\sigma^2 - \mu^3.
\end{align}